# How to attach a PDF as a EmailAttachment using Xamarin.Essentials?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I am using this tutorial by James Montemagno on [Xamarin Essentials](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/sharing-files-attachments-xamarin-essentials/) on how to attach documents on using IEmailService. How do you attach a Syncfusion PDFDocument as an email attachment?

```
using (MyTestPdfDocument document = new MyTestPdfDocument())
{
    //Save the document
    using (MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        document.Save(pdfStream);
        FormattableString formattedEmail = $"\n-ExWU version-\nExpress WriteUp";

        try
        {
            var message = new EmailMessage
            {
                Subject = "Hello",
                Body = "World",
            };

            //var fn = "Attachment.pdf";
            var file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, document);//Close the document

            message.Attachments.Add(new EmailAttachment(file));

            await _emailService.ComposeAsync(message);

            }
            catch (FeatureNotSupportedException)
            {
                await PageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("", "Email is not supported on this device", "Ok");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't use Syncfusion or Xamarin. It seems to me that you'll likely need to either a) save the PDF you generate to a file and then attach that file, or b) (assuming EmailAttachment _and_ Syncfusion support this) write the PDF you generate to a `MemoryStream` and create the attachment from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using a DependencyService below. `EmailAttachment` constructor requires a file path of the document that you save not the actual document. After making slight modifications to James' code, I was able to create a file path for my pdf and a dependency service to draw my contents of my pdf to the stream.

```
try
{
    var message = new EmailMessage
    {
        Subject = "Hello",
        Body = "World",
    };

    var fn = "attachment.pdf";
    var filePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fn);
    string folderPath = DependencyService.Get<IDirectoryService>().SavePath(pdfStream, filePath);

    message.Attachments.Add(new EmailAttachment(folderPath));
    await _emailService.ComposeAsync(message);
}


catch (FeatureNotSupportedException)
{
    await PageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("", "Email is not supported on this device", "Ok");
}

catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

iOS Implementation

```
public class DirectoryService : IDirectoryService
{
    public string SavePath(Stream inputStream, string fileName)
    {
        //Create a new file with the input file name in the Library folder
        var m_filepath = fileName;

        //Write the contents of the pdf to the newly created file
        using (MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            inputStream.Position = 0;
            inputStream.CopyTo(tempStream);
            File.WriteAllBytes(m_filepath, tempStream.ToArray());
        }
        return m_filepath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can attach a Syncfusion PDF document as an email attachment using Xamarin Essentials by using following steps,

- Create and save PDF document into folder
- Get the whole path of PDF file
- Send that PDF document to Email attachment using Xamarin Essentials

We have created the sample for the same which can be downloaded from below link,

[Sample to attach PDF as an Email attachment](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/249995/ze/EmailAttachment-1770740900)